# A question about Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem right now. I have already known the existence of a complement. And according to the textbook, the conjugacy part will use some concepts of sovable groups, but some special case can be proved first.$$$$
Suppose a complement $H$ of a normal Hall subgroup $N$ of $G$ is abelian, then all complements to $N$ are conjugate.$$$$
What I have thought: Since H is abelian, then H is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.(Suppose $H=P_1 \times P_2 ... \times P_n$) And since $( |H| ,|N| )=1$, Sylow subgroups of $H$ are also Sylow subgroups of $G$. Now let $K$ be another complement of $N$. Similar to the argument above, $K$ can be written as $Q_1 \times Q_2 ... \times Q_n$. Then use the second part of the Sylow theorem, every $P_i$ is conjugate to $Q_i$.(i.e $P_i = g_i Q_i {g_i}^{-1}$  for some $g_i$) And here's my question: if these $g_i$ are the same element of $G$, then $H$ and $K$ are conjugate, but how to prove it? I'm stucked here. Am I close to the answer? Or I just came to a wrong way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's prove it by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then your argument using Sylow's Theorem works, so suppose that $n>1$.

Now by Sylow's Theorem, there exists $g_1 \in G$ with $Q_1^{g_1}=P_1$. Then, by replacing $K$ by its conjugate $K^{g_1}$, we may effectively assume that $P_1=Q_1$.

Let $M  = N_G(P_1)$. Then $M$ contains both $H$ and $K$, and they are abelian complements of $M \cap N$, so by induction (with $N$ replaced by $\langle M \cap N,P_1 \rangle$), there exists $g_2 \in M$ with $(Q_2 \times \cdots \times Q_n)^{g_2} = (P_2 \times \cdots \times P_n)$. Then $H^{g_2}=K$ and we are done.

Note that in terms of the original groups $H$ and $K$  we have $K^{g_1g_2} = H$.